# Local Storage deleted in ios13

Tags: jquery, local-storage, ios13.2

We are using different concept like

```
1.localStorage.setItem("key","value");
2. preference.put("key","value");
3. memorypreference.put("key","value");
4. globalpreference.put("key","value");
```

But the stored key itself is deleted once we kill or destroyed the app from background task in iOS 13 device (iPad).

Surprisingly this data are not getting deleted(or retained) for same scenario in xcode 11.2 simulator(tested with iPad OS 13.2) and even lower version of ios devices.

Is there any work around for it?

Comment: "localStorage.put"?

Comment: destroy the app? Mean close it?

Comment: When we use localStorage.put  with someone value, we can retrive the data only till app in active state.

Comment: Destroy means kill or close the app from background itself, but not uninstall the app!

Comment: Is iPad in iOS 13.2 expecting any plist keys?